# Remove Line numbers from Notepad++ file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have received a very long file. It has 1000+ lines of SQL code. Each line start with line number.

```
14      PROCEDURE sp_processRuleset(pop_id IN NUMBER);
15  
16       -- clear procedure for preview mode to clean crom_population_member_temp table and global variables
17       PROCEDURE sp_commit; -- 28-Oct-09 J.Luo
18  
19       -- The rule Set string for the Derived Population Member Preview
20       -- The preview mode will set gv_context_ruleSet by setContext_ruleSet,
21       -- sp_processRuleset uses gv_context_ruleSet to build derived population instead of getting rules from crom_rule_set table
22       gv_context_ruleSet VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;  -- 27-Oct-09 J.Luo
23          -- The population Role Id for the Derived Population Member Preview
```

I want to remove only line numbers using NotePad++ Find+Replace functionality. Is there any regex available to get this done ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174643/1870232) is the easiest way.

Other handy way (scrolling a 1K lines is not much IMO) could be :

*Block Selection* using <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and dragging your mouse, like following:

[image]

Comment: Is that your Notepad++? What style (theme) do you use? :) Mine currently is twilight but sometimes I go Zenburn. +1 btw. Nicely shown.

Comment: @konsolebox Mine is "Deep black", since I used a user defined language which was initially formatted on this theme. BTW _Twilight_ is nice too :D

Comment: I'll try that sometime just for fun :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dY3tN4/2)**

Comment: + Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: "^\s*\d+" works even if there is a small space at start of line :)

Answer (score 3):

Open Replace window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and run <kbd>Replace All</kbd> with these settings:

1. Find what: `^\s*\d+`
2. Replace with: (empty)
3. Search mode: Regular expression

Notes:

- `\s` can also be `[[:space:]]` or `[ \t]`
- `\d` can also be `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`
- If the new edit is correct, the pattern `\s*` that matches the leading space may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one if you have colon after numbers

```
^\d+:
```