# Delete Line Numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How I can delete line numbers on each line? I try  `[[:d:]]` regular expression but not working
Example:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAhoa.png

Comment: Please don't use an image, paste text.  Also show some example text from the file that you want to change and what your expected output should look like.  Lastly show the exact regex you tried.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174602/remove-line-numbers-from-notepad-file) post, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the image you've posted but assuming the possibility of whitespace behind the line number use the following:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or go into the find window. Select the replace tab and set search mode to Regular Expression.

Use this expression: `^\h*Line\h*\d+:\h*`

Leave the replace box with an empty value and press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

This will transform, for example, this:

```
    Line 198135: Stuff
    Line 198136: you
    Line 198140: need to keep
    Line 198143: ...
    Line 198144: ...
    Line 198145: ...
    Line 198146: ...
    Line 198147: ...
    Line 198148: ...
    Line 198149: ...
    Line 198150: ...
    Line 198152: ...
    Line 198153: ...
    Line 198155: ...
    Line 198156: ...
    Line 198157: ...
    Line 198158: ...
    Line 198159: ...
    Line 198160: ...
    Line 198161: ...
    Line 198162: ...
    Line 198174: ...
    Line 198175: ...
    Line 198176: ...
    Line 198181: ...
    Line 198183: ...
    Line 198184: ...
    Line 198185: ...
    Line 198186: ...
    Line 198190: ...
```

into this:

```
Stuff
you
need to keep
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
```